# How to prove that This limit was used in deriving the Poisson density

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

[image]

From my understanding is to use l'hopital's rule is that right?

Please help me explain.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the rate of the Poisson process is $\lambda$. Then in small time interval $\Delta t$, the probability of one event occurring is $\lambda \Delta t$. The probability of no event occurring is $1-\lambda \Delta t$. Consider time $0$ to $t$ and cut it into a large number of $n$ intervals. Then the probability of $m$ events occurring in time $t$ is

$$C^n_m (1-\lambda \frac{t}{n})^{n-m}(\lambda \frac{t}{n})^m$$

$$=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}(1-\lambda \frac{t}{n})^{n-m}(\lambda \frac{t}{n})^m$$

$$=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!n^m}(\lambda t)^m(1-\frac{\lambda t}{n})^{n-m}$$
$$=\frac{(\lambda t)^m}{m!}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{n^m}(1-\frac{\lambda t}{n})^n(1-\frac{\lambda t}{n})^{-m}$$

Under the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have

$$P=\frac{(\lambda t)^m}{m!}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}{n^m}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{\lambda t}{n})^n\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{\lambda t}{n})^{-m}$$
$$=\frac{(\lambda t)^m}{m!}\times 1 \times e^{-\lambda t}\times 1$$
$$=\frac{(\lambda t)^m e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall in Poisson formulation $p \approx \frac{\lambda}{n}$, so when you have $(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^n \to_n e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: Hi, so ne^(-lambda) is the right answer? So I don't need the l'hopital's rule? Thank you!

Comment: no $\to_n$ is a short-hand notation for limit. The limit is $e^{-\lambda}$